# Echo some text if current date & time is more than date & time stored in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to `echo` some text in `PHP` **if current time `IST` is more than time stored in `Mysql`**

Stored Time: `2017-09-24 16:36:15`

Current Time (IST): `2017-09-24 16:46:15`

I tried:

```
<?php
require_once 'vclass.php';
require_once 'message.php';


$vreg = new Validation();

$stmt = $vreg->runQuery("SELECT * FROM validation WHERE vid=1"); 
$stmt->execute(); 
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
$vusrmaile = $row['svdate'];
$vusrmail = $row['vdate'];
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
$date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s ', time());

            if($date > $vusrmail){ 
                $msg = "
              <div class='alert alert-error'>

                    <strong><center>Process</center></strong>
              </div>
              ";

        }
?>
```

From the above code, I am not getting the result as expected.

Comment: Use datetime objects to compare the two

Comment: @Qirel How to do so?

Comment: Should be `$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s ', time());`   for the 24 hour clock.. the small h is for the 12 hour clock

Comment: Create objects instead of datestirngs. `$vusrmail = new DateTime($row['vdate']); $date = new DateTime;` and compare them as `if ($date > $vusrmail)`. It'll work with datestrings too, but you need ot use the proper format (see Raymonds comment above) - but datetime objects are always better to work with.

Comment: `echo $date;` and you'll see what you're getting, as compared to what you're really wanting to get. Again as Qirel said, see @RaymondNijland 's comment which most likely is your solution here. If it is, he should submit an (detailed) answer for it.

Comment: @Qirel small question... Can we insert `date & time` of `IST` in the database which system is at `America/New York`? **Difference between `America/New York` & `IST` is `+09:30`**

Comment: Why wouldn't you have both at the same timezone? It makes it a lot easier. But yeah, it's possible, might want to use timestamps instead though.

Comment: @Qirel So, how to use timestamps? Should I use in my **vclass.php** which is having `$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO validation(vdate,svdate) 
                                                VALUES(now(),NOW() + INTERVAL 15 HOUR)");`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the timestamp from your MySQL database into [Unix Time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) and then compare with the current time (represented in Unix Time):

```
<?php
require_once 'vclass.php';
require_once 'message.php';


$vreg = new Validation();

$stmt = $vreg->runQuery("SELECT * FROM validation WHERE vid=1"); 
$stmt->execute(); 
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
$vusrmaile = $row['svdate'];
$vusrmail = strtotime($row['vdate']); // Convert MySQL datetime string to Unix Time (this will depend on current timezone)
$date = time(); // Current Unix time (this is independent of timezone)

            if($date > $vusrmail){ 
                $msg = "
              <div class='alert alert-error'>

                    <strong><center>Process</center></strong>
              </div>
              ";

        }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I went with **Raymond's** answer. A small question... Can we insert `date & time` of `IST` in the database which system is at `America/New York`? **Difference between `America/New York` & `IST` is `+09:30`**